# Steps to protect sensitive information in a MySQL Database

Tags: security, encryption, mysql

I consider myself to be quite a good programmer but I know very little about sever administration. I'm sorry if these questions are noobish but I would really appreciate some advice or links on steps I can take to make this more secure.

I've completed a project for a client that involves storing some very sensitive information, ie personal details of big donors. From a programming perspective it's protected using user authentication.

I don't mind spending some money if it means the info will be more secure, what other steps should I take?

1. Can the database be encrypted some how so that even if the server is compromised people can't just dump the mysqldb and have everything?
2. Is it worth purchasing an ssl certificate?
3. The site is currently hosted on a personal hosting plan with a reasonably trustworthy host. Would a virtual private server be more secure? Are there special hosts I can use that take additional steps to protect info (ie would it be more secure on amazon s3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a side note to the specific question, I would recommend reading some books on computer/programming security. Some good ones are *19 Deadly Sins of Software Security* and *Writing Solid Code*.

---

1. You don’t need to encrypt the database itself, just encrypt the data before storing it. (Make sure to use real, cryptographically-secure algorithms instead of making one up yourself.)
2. Using SSL is definitely an important step if you want to avoid MITM attacks or snooping. A certificate allows you to use SSL without having to take extra steps like installing a self-signed one on each of the client systems (not to mention other benefits like revocation of compromised certs and such).
3. It depends on just how sensitive the information is and how bad leakage would be. You may want to read some reviews of hosts to get an idea of how good the host is. (If possible, sort the reviews ascending by rating and look at the bad reviews to see if they are objective problems that could apply to you and/or have to do with security, or if they are just incidental or specific issues to that reviewer.) As for the “cloud”, you would kind of be taking a chance since real-world security and privacy of it has yet to be determined. Obviously, if you do go with it, you’ll want a notable, trustworthy host like Amazon or Microsoft since they have benefits like accountability and work constantly and quickly to fix any problems.

HTH